# My Bluetooth Hands-free is not connecting with win-10 PC through Bluetooth Dongle, it requires PIN but Hands-free don't have one?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, bluetooth, wireless-headset

I am trying to connect my Bluetooth handsfree to my Desktop PC through Bluetooth USB dongle.

> **PC Specifications;**

- > Windows 10, v 1709 (OS Build 16299.15) 64-Bit  OS,
- > x64 Intel i5-6600 Processor, 8GB RAM
- > No Built-in Bluetooth.

**Bluetooth USB Dongle:**
[image]
[image]

**Bluetooth Handsfree:**

[image]

> This Handsfree only have 3 buttons, volume Up/Down and On/OFF, there
>   is no display, no way to enter any pin/Code.

I have connected Dongle to My PC's usb 2.0 port, and windows installed the driver with specs,
Dongle Appears here in device manager-:
[image]
I manually installed the driver-:
[image]
[image]
[image]
These are the specs of the driver.
[image]

After this, I tried to connect my Android Smartphone, and it was successful, I could even send/receive files.

But when I tried to connect my Handsfree, it finds the handsfree,
[image]
And tries to connect.
[image]

> Bu then asks for Pin, but I don't have a pin on my handsfree, so I
>   tried entering 0000 or 1111 or 1234, but an error occurs saying Check
>   Pin and try again.

**I don't understand, when I connect this handsfree to my Android phone, and Laptop (with Built-in Bluetooth running win 10), there is no pin code asking, handsfree automatically gets connected.**

Please guide me on what would be the reason, is there something else I need to do in settings, or something else.??

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If entering `0000` as PIN did not work, try the old classical interface for pairing:

- Right-click the traybar Bluetooth Devices notification area icon and choose
  *Join a Personal Area Network*.
  An Explorer interface will open to
  *Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers*.
- Click *Add a Bluetooth device*
- Press the pairing button on the device
- When asked for PIN, leave blank and continue to connect.

Leaving the PIN blank does not work through the Windows 10 Settings applet,
so for devices that don't have a pin one must use the older Control Panel interface.